# exchange web services with calendar appointments

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use exchange web services impersonation to add appointments into calendars. I am using Exchange Web Service Manager API and it worked fine when I tested with one account. Since my application will have to do this operation with about 20 000 accounts I am wondering what is the most efficient way to do it? (if it's possible)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only option you have is to call CreateAppointment in loop. Each iteration has to have the appropriate user impersonation before creating the appointment using **Appointment** class

Check this URL for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633661%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx